# how to show this function is increasing

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I need to show $\forall p\in\mathbb{R} \exists M_p>0\ni e^x>x^p$

$g(1)=e-1>0, g(0)=1>0, g'(x)=e^x-px^{p-1}, g'(0)=1>0$ please help

Comment: You can use the fact that $e^x=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{p!}$ for every real $x$.

Comment: Where is the MathJax? sending images is not ok even for beginners.

Comment: What does "$\exists M_p>0\ni e^x>x^p$" mean?

Comment: I think you are missing a $\forall x>M_p$ before $\text{e}^x>x^p$.